# Two separate rooms with dimmable lights different brightness

Tags: electrical, light

Quick question: why do two separate dimmers in separate rooms have different max brightness, despite having exactly the same brand dimmers and lights? My google queries led nowhere and I'm hoping someone has encountered this before.

Comment: When you say same brand lights, do you mean the actual bulbs? LED or incandescent? Have you checked that the bulbs are the same spec in lumens (not Watts, and definitely not Watts equivalent)? If you take the bulbs out and put them in a non-dimmable fitting, do they look the same? How are you comparing the brightness? The appearance in a room depends on the size, decoration, and contents of the room as well as the bulb.  If you swap bulbs, does the brightness stay with the bulb or the room? What about if you swap switches?

Comment: Same *brand* dimmers? Or same *exact model* dimmers? Also, many dimmers now have an adjustment to set min and/or max brightness. Actually, max should always be "100%" but due to the way dimmers work, that is not *necessarily* the case.

Comment: What are the wall coverings and colors? What are the color temps of the bulbs? I've got dimmable, color temp adjustable bulbs in 2 different rooms in my house. When I set both sets of bulbs at 100% brightness, 4000k temperature, the rooms look different because one room is full of white cabinets and blue walls, while the other room has cream colored walls and cabinets. Exact same brand/model bulbs, both being controlled by HomeAssistant, totally different look.

Comment: What @FreeMan is saying, check your eyesight

Comment: Thank you all for providing the right questions to ask. This is actually happening to 2 buddies of mine and I will not know the answers until a few days later, after which I will update the question with the details.